# Proving that $r$ is differentiable on $V\times B(0;\delta)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I want to solve the following problem: Let $V\subset U$ be open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $\delta > 0$ is a number such that if $x\in V$ and $|h| < \delta$ then $x+h \in U$. Let $B(0;\delta)$ be the open ball centered at $x=0$ and with radius $\delta$. If $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is differentiable at every point of $U$ and $x_{0}\in V$ is fixed, the mapping $r: V \times B(0;\delta) \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ defined by $r(x,h) = f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x_{0})h$ is differentiable at every point of $V \times B(0;\delta)$. The notation $f'(x_{0})h$ means the derivative of $f$ at $x_{0}$ evaluated at $h$.

**My work:** Let $(x,h) \in V\times B(0;\delta)$ be fixed. Define $T: V\times B(0;\delta) \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ by:
$$T(y,s) = f'(x+h)(y+s) -f'(x)y - f'(x_{0})s$$
Then, $T$ is proved to be linear on $\mathbb{R}^{2m} \cong \mathbb{R}^{m}\times \mathbb{R}^{m}$. We define:
$$\tilde{r}(y,s) = r((x,h)+(y,s))-r(x,h)-T(y,s)$$
whenever $x+y \in V$ and $h + s \in B(0;\delta)$. With a little algebra, we can write $\tilde{r}$ as:
$$\tilde{r}(y,s) = [f(x+y+h+s)-f(x+h)-f'(x+h)(y+s)] - [f(x+y)-f(x)-f'(x)y]$$
Since $x+h \in U$ and also $x+y \in U$, $f$ is differentiable at both these points. This implies $\lim_{(y,s)\to (0,0)}\tilde{r}(y,s)/||(y,s)|| = 0$, which proves the claim, since $(x,h)$ was arbitrary.

In order to the above conclusion $\lim_{(y,s)\to (0,0)}\tilde{r}(y,s)/||(y,s)|| = 0$ to hold, we need to have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{(y,s)\to (0,0)} \frac{f(x+h+y+s)-f(x+h)-f'(x+h)(y+s)}{||(y,s)||} = 0 \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
and:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{(y,s)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)-f'(x)y}{||(y,s)||} = 0 \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{eqnarray}
And I'm not 100% sure these conditions are true. But I think they are. My reasoning is: (\ref{1}) is true because $(y,s)\to (0,0)$ implies $y+s \to 0$, so (\ref{1}) becomes the derivative at $x+h$ and (\ref{2}) seems to be true since:
$$\lim_{(y,s)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)-f'(x)y}{||(y,s)||}  = \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)-f'(x)y}{||y||} = 0$$
since $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

Is my proof correct? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I haven't fully read your work, but this is a very simple consequence of the chain rule, and if your proof is right, you're just proving the chain rule in a special case.

Comment: I was supposed to prove it using the definition. That's why I didn't use the chain rule!